# How did Prabowo make his money?

Tags: indonesia

Prabowo, one of the presidential candidates in Indonesia is very rich.

Some say he is corrupt or effectively corrupt. He's a general, not a businessman. Also generals are prohibited from doing business in Indonesia.

So how did he get rich?

I know Jokowi has a furniture business. What about Prabowo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He was dishonourably discharged from the Army in 1998, so he is not now a General, and he is not prohibited from working inside Indonesia.  Since then he has been a businessman.

He is from an aristocratic Javanese family and was already wealthy. He used his family wealth to purchase a paper making company and expanded it to a highly diversified company. He owns the Nusantara Group (with others) which controls 27 businesses in Indonesia and abroad, including pulp and paper making, energy production, mining and car import. His companies have provided him with over $150 million.

He has wealth invested in various funds and he was named in the "paradise papers"

Comment: And someone having 150 million dollars starting from scratch still wanna be president? I mean we know how Bill Gates got rich. How did he? Good enough answer. I would appreciate more detail

Comment: Edited to add a few details.  He wasn't starting from scratch, he is from a wealthy family. He (or him and his family) now own a large and diverse business. No doubt he has used all the advantages that a being a political and military leader gives to get an edge in business, and has avoided tax as far as he has been able.